# How do I get rid of this error while compiling my \latex document?

Tags: errors, lists, compiling

I'm using MikeTeX 2.9.5823 release, with WinEdit 2.91 as my front-end text editor, on a Windows XP Service Pack 2 computer.

I'm using the amsart document class.

I've inserted several numbered lists, using the `enumerate` environment, along with several `itemize` environments nested within them.

When I compile my LaTeX file, the following text shows in the console.

```
Command Line:   bibtex.exe "Functional Analysis I Final Exam"
Startup Folder: C:\Documents and Settings\Crowe\Desktop\Functional Analysis I Final Exam

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9)
The top-level auxiliary file: Functional Analysis I Final Exam.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file Functional Analysis I Final Exam.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file Functional Analysis I Final Exam.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file Functional Analysis I Final Exam.aux
(There were 3 error messages)


Command Line:   texify.exe --pdf --tex-option=--interaction=errorstopmode --tex-option=--synctex=-1 "C:\Documents and Settings\Crowe\Desktop\Functional Analysis I Final Exam\Functional Analysis I Final Exam.tex"
Startup Folder: C:\Documents and Settings\Crowe\Desktop\Functional Analysis I Final Exam

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (MiKTeX 2.9)
entering extended mode

("C:/Documents and Settings/Crowe/Desktop/Functional Analysis I Final Exam/Func
tional Analysis I Final Exam.tex"
LaTeX2e <2015/10/01> patch level 2
Babel <3.9m> and hyphenation patterns for 69 languages loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amscls\amsart.cls"
Document Class: amsart 2015/03/04 v2.20.2
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsmath.sty"
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amstext.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsgen.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsbsy.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsopn.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\umsa.fd")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\amsfonts.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\graphics.cfg")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pdftex-def\pdftex.def"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty"))))
("Functional Analysis I Final Exam.aux")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\umsa.fd")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\umsb.fd")
("C:\Documents and Settings\Crowe\Local Settings\Application Data\PrograMS\MiKT
eX 2.9\tex\context\base\supp-pdf.mkii"
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) [1{C:/Documents and Settings/Crowe/Local Settings/Application Data/MiKTeX/2.9
/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
Overfull \hbox (2.22289pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 115--116
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 Their sum is al-ways bounded, but their com-pos-ite need not 
be bounded. 

Overfull \hbox (2.22289pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 116--117
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 Their com-pos-ite is al-ways bounded, but their sum need not 
be bounded. 

Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active [2]
[3]
Runaway argument?
C3{a)] The Banach fixed point theorem. [2+8 = 10 marks] \item [C3(b)]\ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \@item was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.226 

?
```

What could be the problem?

And how do I fix it?

Comment: you have not shown your input but you have a bracket missing somewhere around   `C3{a)] The Banach fixed point theorem. [2+8 = 10 marks] `

Comment: oh you have a curly bracket `{`  before the `a` and a round bracket `)` after the `a`. I guess that was not intended?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you very much. That was exactly the problem, but the message in the console seemed to suggest as if there was some issue with my "itemizations or enumerations". Actually, I'm a visually impaired person. And, I'm only using the High Contrast Black (Large) setting for my only accessibility support option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have not shown your input but you have a mis-matched brackets here:

```
 C3{a)] The Banach fixed point theorem. [2+8 = 10 marks] 
   ^
```

You have a curly bracket `{` (which should be `(` most likely) before the `a` and a round bracket `)` after the `a`.